# How can I match the colors of lines and legend entries in ggplot2?

Tags: ggplot2, legend, legend-properties

I have a dataframe of some spectra (one x-value, several y-values) and want to plot them in one graph. For this purpose, I want to use ggplot. After some research, I found a way to do so, but I want to change the color of the lines from black to grey, representing a dcrease in concentration.

```
if (!require("ggplot2")) install.packages("ggplot2")

set.seed(230527)

df.tmp <- data.frame(x = runif(25), 
                     y = cbind(runif(25),
                               runif(25),
                               runif(25),
                               runif(25),
                               runif(25))
                     )
                     
if (!require("reshape")) install.packages("reshape")

df.spec <- data.frame(x = df.tmp[,1], y = df.tmp[,2:6])
df.spec <- melt(df.spec, id.vars = "x")

ggplot(df.spec, aes(x = x, y = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image: raw picture]

Therefore, I defined a color palette.

`palette.spec <- fields::designer.colors(col = c("black", "lightgrey"), n = NCOL(df.tmp)-1)`

```
if (!require("ggplot2")) install.packages("ggplot2")

set.seed(230527)

df.tmp <- data.frame(x = runif(25), 
                     y = cbind(runif(25),
                               runif(25),
                               runif(25),
                               runif(25),
                               runif(25))
                     )
                     
palette.spec <- fields::designer.colors(col = c("black", "lightgrey"), n = NCOL(df.tmp)-1)

if (!require("reshape")) install.packages("reshape")

df.spec <- data.frame(x = df.tmp[,1], y = df.tmp[,2:6])
df.spec <- melt(df.spec, id.vars = "x")

ggplot(df.spec, aes(x = x, y = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line() + 
  scale_color_manual(values = palette.spec)
```

[image: right color, wrong legend labels]

Now, the color of the lines and the legend fits, but I also have to change the names of the legend entries.

When doing so, the names are correct, but also the color of the lines in the graph changes.

```
if (!require("ggplot2")) install.packages("ggplot2")

set.seed(230527)

df.tmp <- data.frame(x = runif(25), 
                     y = cbind(runif(25),
                               runif(25),
                               runif(25),
                               runif(25),
                               runif(25))
                     )
                     
palette.spec <- fields::designer.colors(col = c("black", "lightgrey"), n = NCOL(df.tmp)-1)

if (!require("reshape")) install.packages("reshape")

df.spec <- data.frame(x = df.tmp[,1], y = df.tmp[,2:6])
df.spec <- melt(df.spec, id.vars = "x")

ggplot(df.spec, aes(x = x, y = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line() + 
  scale_color_manual(values = palette.spec,
                     limits = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
```

[image: right entries, wrong colour]

Is it possible to match the colors of the lines and the legend entries?

Bonus: Is it also possible to insert a manual offset between the different lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting `limits` you are defining the valid values for the colour scale.
Because none of the values in `variable` match them, they get mapped to `NA`
and a corresponding grey colour.

Instead of specifying `limits`, either define the variable labes in your
data, or use `labels`:

```r
ggplot(df.spec, aes(x = x, y = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line() + 
  scale_color_manual(
    values = palette.spec,
    labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
  )
```

[image]